# Using Scanner with a custom delimiter skips trailing empty tokens

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a simple Scanner as below.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("...<CSV file>"));
sc.useDelimiter(",");
```

I observe that the Scanner above skips the trailing empty Tokens.

Is there a way I could get empty trailing tokens also using a Scanner?

like how `String.split(pattern, -1)` would include the empty trailing `tokens` ?

Comment: can you add sample file content and the expected out?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a Scanner to get the final empty token which is beyond the last delimiter, however it requires a bit of special handling:

1. Construct a regular expression to match the zero-width position in front of the delimiter. You will need to use the zero-width positive lookahead construct `(?=X)`. This String or Pattern will be your argument to Scanner::useDelimiter. For a simple case where you have comma-separated values on a single line, that would be `useDelimiter("(?=,)")`.
2. Inside the processing loop, you will need to strip the actual delimiter from the front of every token except for the first token. See below.
3. If the first token starts with the delimiter, this represents a special case where the Scanner has skipped one empty token at the beginning of input. Sound familiar? You will likely need to handle this special case if you are concerned about empty tokens at the beginning of input.

Finally, you can combine these three modifications into a wrapper class which provides similar functionality to the original Scanner.